# Parsing a char array in c

Tags: c, pointers, tokenize

I am trying to parse a c char array. It is for class so I have to use c. I am having problems splitting the tokens

I need to be able to accept two different parameters in the following formats:
[1234]
or
[1234 abcd]

When I parse the "[1234 abcd]" I have no issues. But, when I try parsing "[1234]" I get a "no match" error. Although, when I try "[1234 ]" I have no issues.

Can anyone tell me why this would be the case?

Below is my test code:

```
$ ./parsemem
Splitting string "[1234 abcd]" into tokens:
ip1:1234, ip2:abcd
var1:1234, var2:abcd
```

parsemem.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//int parse()
int parse(char *str, char *v1, char *v2)
{
 char string[11];
 strcpy(string,str);
 char * pch;
 char ip[1][5];
 int i=0;

 printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",string);
 pch = strtok (string," []");
 while (pch != NULL)
 {
   strcpy(ip[i],pch);
   pch = strtok (NULL, " []");
   i++;
 }

 printf("ip1:%d, ip2:%s\n", atoi(ip[0]), ip[1]);
 strcpy(v1,ip[0]);
 strcpy(v2,ip[1]);

 return 0;
}

int main()
{
char str[] ="[1234 abcd]";
//char str[] ="[1234]";
//char str[] ="[1234 ]";
char var1[5];
char var2[5];

parse(str,var1,var2);

printf("var1:%d, var2:%s\n", atoi(var1), var2);

}
```

@AndreyT

I am having a similar problem again. When I tried to integrate this into my program using [1234] as an argument I am getting  “No match.” Although if I put a space before the ] like [1234 ] There is no problem with strtok.

Having the ] at the end of my string I want to tokenize is a problem. Any ideas why this is the case?

```
$./parsemem [1234]
./parsemem: No match.


$./parsemem [1234 ]
Splitting string " [1234" into tokens:
ip1:1234, ip2:
var1:1234, var2:
```

Comment: What do you mean by "parse' in this case? (hint hint)

Comment: It runs fine on my machine. What output should expect when str="[1234]"?

Comment: [1234] should output 1234 but it wasn't working for me. I found the answer-see below. My array sizes were not correct.

Comment: I don't know where you "No match" comes from. I don't see anything in your code that would print "No match". I think it is safe to say that your code does not even run in this case, meaning that the problem is elsewhere. Not related to your code at all. Judging by the format of the "No match" message I would even guess that it comes from your OS, meaning that your "parsemem" program does not even run.

Comment: The "No match" message looks like a message from the shell, which might interprets `[1234]` as some kind of special expression. Try running it as `./parsemem '[1234]'`, i.e. wrap the argument into single quotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String `"[1234 abcd]"` requires a char array of size 12 (at least). Inside `parse` you are copying it into an array of size 11. Why?

Also, your `ip` array is declared with first size `1`, which means that it is illegal to access `ip[1]`. You can only access `ip[0]`.

In other words, your code is hopelessly overrunning array memory in several places. The behavior is undefined. Until you fix the above errors (and any other errors of that nature), any questions about the run-time behavior of your code make no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I changed the array sizes and it is working as expected....  Splitting string "[1234]" into tokens:
ip1:1234, ip2:
var1:1234, var2: